# Backbone collection.each() is not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am receiving the following message when I try to use Backbone's collection.each() method:

**TypeError: Object function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'each'**.

I'm learning Backbone from some Jeffrey Way tutorials; I entered identical code to his, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'besim dauti',
        age: 15,
        occupation: 'web developer'
    }
});

var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(person) {
            var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
            this.$el.append(personView.render().el)
        }, this)
        return this;
    }
});

var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template( $('#personTemplate').html() ),

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
        return this;
    }
});

var PeopleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});

var peopleCollection = new PeopleCollection([
    {
        name: 'besim',
        age: 25,
        occupation: 'web developer'
    },
    {
        name: 'gaurav',
        age: 25,
        occupation: 'web designer'
    },
    {
        name: 'jeffry',
        age: 27
    }
])

var peopleView = new PeopleView ({collection: PeopleCollection});
$(document.body).append(peopleView.render().el);
```

Why is there this problem with the `.each()` function? I typed the code identically and, for Jeffrey, it worked as expected, but for me it displayed this error. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What happens when you add a new line at the start of PeopleView's render like `console.log(this.collection);`?  The general problem appears to be that `this.collection` isn't what you think it is (because if it was, it'd have an `each` method).  So if you look at what it actually is in the console (with Firebug, Chrome developer tools, etc.), it will likely help you figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialise the `PeopleCollection`.

See: `var peopleView = new PeopleView ({collection: PeopleCollection});`

You are passing in the raw constructor and not an instance of it.

You should do this:

```
var peopleCollection = new PeopleCollection(); // Create an instance of PeopleCollection
var peopleView = new PeopleView ({collection: peopleCollection}); // Pass it to peopleView
```

If you are familiar with OOP (Object orientated programming) think of `PeopleCollection` as a class and `var peopleCollection = new PeopleCollection()` as an instance of that class. You must work with instances.

You will also encounter an error inside your `.each` because you capitalised `person`. Change to:

```
this.collection.each(function(person) {
   var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
   this.$el.append(personView.render().el)
}, this)
```

Comment: yes i changed the P to p but does'nt work again. the code is the same like jeff code i don't know why the same message. thanks for answering.

Comment: @user2397353 can you `console.log(this.collection.models);` before your `this.collection.each` and tell me what it says.

Comment: @user2397353 Did you definitely change `var peopleView = new PeopleView ({collection: PeopleCollection});` `to var peopleView = new PeopleView ({collection: peopleCollection});` because in your edited answer it is still the same, and would cause the exact error you are talking about.

Comment: thank you so much. that's was the point i mistaked peopleCollection not PeopleCollection.

Comment: @GeorgeReith is it underscore each method ?? if yes then where is _ sign . please let me know . thank you

Comment: @Mahi http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods they are made available as properties on Collections

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/kbLES/

```
var peopleView = new PeopleView ({collection: peopleCollection});
$(document.body).append(peopleView.render().el);
```

It looks like you may have a dependency issue.  Can you post how you are including your scripts on the page?

Comment: here is my index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <script id="personTemplate" type="text/template">
  <strong><%= name %></strong> (<%=age%>) - <%= occupation %>
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


can be the problem i'm working on local host or not

Comment: I don' see the link but I am fairly sure of your issue.  I get the same error in jsfiddle when I remove underscore.  Double check you that underscore is included before backbone and that you are not getting a 404.

Comment: Move your scripts to the bottom of your page.  Change the order so it is jquery, underscore, backbone, main.

Comment: yes, underscore is before backbone, even i don't know what's the problem, can be problem working in localhost or not

Comment: Your code will work locally.  You are just missing the library.

Comment: which library do you think i'm missing. i included the same libraries as he did. can i sent to you all folder with files, and if you can test in your computer please

Comment: Underscore...Here replace your underscore script tag with this one: `<script src="https://raw.github.com/documentcloud/underscore/master/underscore-min.js"></script>`